# How do I include a C++ class in a namespace into Cython?

Tags: c++, cython

I'm trying to create a wrap for a set C++ classes so I can use it in Python using Cython. This is what I have tried so far.

```
cdef extern from "HilClass.h" namespace "acro":
    cdef cppclass _HilClass "HilClass":
        void start()

cdef class HilClass:
    cdef _HilClass *ptr

    cpdef start(self):
        self.ptr.start()
```

That doesn't compile. I get the errors below, which by now I've come to learn that a possible cause is that it doesn't find the class. So after checking I had properly included the headers and sources I looked into the .cpp generated by Cython. I searched for `acro` but was unable to find it. It wasn't mentioned anywhere in the code.

```
error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
... (more warning and errors related to HilClass)
```

This is when I decided to change the second line to.

```
    cdef cppclass _HilClass "acro::HilClass":
```

This does compile. But this wasn't done in any example/tutorial I've found. So my question is, I'm I missing something and will my 'workaround' keep working reliably.

NOTE: I'm not interested in creating an instance of this class from within Python or Cython, I just need it to wrap around a HilClass pointer.

**EDIT:**
This is the code inside 'HilClass.h'. 'acrophobe.h' has a few class forward declarations, enums, `typedef unint#_t ####`, and includes stdint.

```
#include "acrophobe.h"

namespace acro {
    class HilClass
    {
    public:
        HilClass(AcrophobeClass *acro_ptr);
        ~HilClass();

        HILSocketClass *sck;

        void start();
        void acrophile_iteration(char dest, lbp::PortID_t PortID);

        void set_activity_iteration_start(bool s);
        // More of these set_activity functions
        void set_activity_logging(bool s);


    private:
        AcrophobeClass *acro;

    };
}
```

Comment: Your problems may be related to code in *HilClass.h* so it is not possible to figure out what is the problem. You may need to include some other headers before *HilClass.h* to fix the problem.

Comment: I believe your workround is reliable. I'm not sure what your original problem is caused by.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define as you have done

```
cdef cppclass _HilClass "acro::HilClass"
```

because you are giving *acro::HilClass* an alias *_HilClass*. You could test what happens if you define

```
cdef cppclass HilClass:
    void start()
```

and then later (the class name is just for an example)

```
cdef class PyHilClass:
    cdef HilClass * ptr
```

I don't see any reason why your solution would not be reliable.

Comment: Well, since I just got a popular question badge on this 4 year old question I guess there are more people ending up here with the same or similar issues.

So far this has been working without any issues and I've used it in many more projects. I'm fairly confident it's indeed reliable.